# Excel set print area not affecting export as PDF layout

Tags: excel, vb.net, printing

ExportAsFixedFormat is not following the pagesetup printarea, I tried to export with ignore print area as true and false and it didn't work.

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(PastaLocal & "\Modelo Pedido.xlsx")
xlApp.Visible = True
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

' Setting print area and exporint as PDF
xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:U55"
xlWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, PastaLocal & "\PedidoTal.pdf", False, True, False)
```

Comment: If you want the `.PrintArea` to be used then you should print to PDF (instead of exporting - which equates to SaveAs PDF and neglects the `PrintArea`).

Comment: Yes, I had this ideia, but I don't know if only windows have all windows versions have this Print as PDF option, I think it's only windows 10+, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have found not pre-specifying the print range works. i.e.

```
printSheet.Range("A1:AT" & lastRowinPrintSheet).ExportAsFixedFormat _ 
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=scorecardFilename, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False
```